# Reverse Cascade in PHP Exception Classes?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I just wanted to double-check if what I just found is default PHP behaviour, because I cannot explain it otherwise. Say you build a custom PHP Exceptions class:

```
<?php
namespace XYZ;

if ( ! class_exists( 'XYZ\CustomException' ) ) {

  class CustomException extends \Exception {

    public function __construct( int $code ) {

        parent::__construct( "The error code is: $code", $code );

    }

  }

}
?>
```

You then launch a PHP script with a content like:

```
try {
  throw new CustomException(1);
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
  echo "regular exception thrown";
} catch ( CustomException $e ) {
  echo "custom exception thrown";
}
```

When running that block, I get `"regular exception thrown"`.

When I reverse the catch blocks of the script to:

```
try {
  throw new CustomException(1);
} catch ( CustomException $e ) {
  echo "custom exception thrown";
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
  echo "regular exception thrown";
}
```

I get `"custom exception thrown"`.

Is it actually default in PHP that child classes of the `Exception` class will be caught by the parent `Exception` handler, if the parent `Exception` class catch block is written first?? Or is this some sort of weird config that is unusual?

Comment: Think of the order as specific to generic, since you've extended Exception with `CustomException`, but other exceptions could have also extended Exception, you should start with the specific catch first.

Edit: this is extra fun when you start getting deeper nestings, eg `LoginAuthException` could extend `AuthException` which extends `Exception`

Comment: hahahahhah gotcha, will stay away from that :'D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception is thrown, it goes through the `try` blocks in order, testing whether the exception is an instance of the specified class, and it stops when it gets to the first matching block. Since `CustomException` is a subclass of `Exception`, the `catch ( \Exception )` block matches this test, so it stops there first.

It's essentially like:

```
if (is_a($e, 'Exception')) {
    echo "regular exception thrown";
} elseif (is_a($e, 'CustomException')) {
    echo "custom exception thrown";
}
```

It doesn't try to find the `catch` block with the closest match, it's just done sequentially. It's your responsibility to order them by specificity.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch) explains this:

> The first `catch` block a thrown exception or error encounters that matches the type of the thrown object will handle the object.

Comment: perfect, cheers! I'm wondering, is there a better doc than php.net? Just because this is not really specified there..

Comment: I just added the line from php.net that specifies it clearly.

Comment: Where does it say that catch blocks match with children of specified Exception classes? I'm asking because I'm afraid of having missed out even more..

Comment: That's just the nature of classes and subclasses.

Comment: "The first catch block a thrown exception or error encounters that matches the type of the thrown object will handle the object" This is the line that assumes knowelge of how object class types work.

Comment: Hmmm so there's no part in the docs that tells with which comparison operator the `catch` keyword can be compared, or sth likely?

Comment: Ah oops @Scuzzy indeed, that's the line I've missed out. Damn completely overread that line, cheers !

Comment: If it didn't match subclasses, `catch (Exception)` would almost never work, since most built-in exceptions are more specific classes. You would always have to list all the possible exceptions you want to catch.

Comment: Yes which is what I was actually doing :') The design totally makes sense! Just outta curiosity, is it possible to trigger an Exception if you're code fails at some point within a try block, making a PHP throw a fatal error or similar, trigger the Exception catch block tied to that respective try block instead? Would just make error displays a little more elegant.

Comment: Use `set_error_handler()` to customize the global error handler. But I'm not sure if it can trigger an exception -- it might run after the stack has been unwound. Check the documentation and try it.

Comment: [this note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#112881) shows how to do it

Comment: @DevelJoe Most fatal errors in PHP are now actually exceptions with the base class `Error`, which is a sibling of `Exception` - both inherit from a bar called `Throwable`. So to catch pretty much everything, you can use `catch(Throwable $e)`

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior. Since your `CustomException` is inheriting `Exception` and your first `catch` is against `Exception` it will stop here first.